# Why were Jews allowed to commit incest?

Tags: marriage

Amram married Yokheved, his aunt, Yitzkhak married Rivkah, his cousin, Yehudah married his daughter-in-law, etc. Why were they allowed to commit incest even though it is prohibited in the Torah. And if the answer is because the Torah hadn't been given to Moshe yet, why was incest ok for the previous generations but not those after Matan Torah?

Comment: According to our sages, the prohibition of marrying reletives is not because of morality, but is considered one of the many Mitzvos whose reasons are unknown or hidden (see Ramban on Vayikra 18:6)

Comment: In addition to what @User123 said, many cases of what you (and modern society) call incest, are actually completely allowed by the Torah, including marrying one's cousin, and even one's niece (though not one's aunt)

Comment: "why was incest ok for the previous generations but not those after Matan Torah?" Could you explain this question? It was forbidden by the Torah, and had not been forbidden before.

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Chizkuni%2C_Exodus.6.20.1?lang=bi

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Sotah.10a.20?lang=bi&p2=Rashi_on_Sotah.10a.20.4

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya. For starters, they weren't Jews.